# Printing a checker board

Tags: c, struct

I am currently writing a checker program which uses alpha-beta pruning and a heuristic to play the game. I am attempting to print out the board at evaluation of the board and I am running into problems getting it to work. My teacher gave us all the code we need to run the program minus the evaluation function and the alpha-beta pruning function. The method for printing the board is in a different class than the methods for finding the best move for the checker game.

Below are par of the search function class header (it doesn't include all of the method calls) and the evalBoard method which is where we want to print the board

```
 double evalBoard1(State *state) {
      int x, y;
      double rval = 0.0;
      double rval2 = 0.0;
      evals++;
      for (x = 0; x < 8; x++)
           for (y = 0; y < 8; y++) {
                if (x % 2 != y % 2 && !empty(state->board[y][x])) {
                     if (king(state->board[y][x])) { /* King */
                          if (((state->board[y][x] & White) && !player1) 
                                  || (!(state->board[y][x] & White) && player1))
                               rval += 2.0;
                else
                    rval2 += 2.0;
                } else if (piece(state->board[y][x])) { /* Piece */
                      if (((state->board[y][x] & White) && !player1)
                             || (!(state->board[y][x] & White) && player1))
                           rval += 1.0;
                      else
                           rval2 += 1.0;
                }
            }
       }
     state->PrintBoard(); //should print the board
     fprintf(stderr,"Value = %g\n",rval); //prints the evaluation of that board
     if(rval <= 0.0) return -10000.0;
     if(rval2 <= 0.0) return 10000.0;
     return rval - rval2;
}

 #ifndef COMPUTER_H
 #define COMPUTER_H

 #define Empty 0x00
 #define Piece 0x20
 #define King 0x60
 #define Red 0x00
 #define White 0x80

 #define number(x) ((x)&0x1f)
 #define empty(x) ((((x)>>5)&0x03)==0?1:0)
 #define piece(x) ((((x)>>5)&0x03)==1?1:0)
 #define king(x) ((((x)>>5)&0x03)==3?1:0)
 #define color(x) ((((x)>>7)&1)+1)

 #define Clear 0x1f

 typedef struct{
     int player;
     char board[8][8];
     char movelist[48][12];  
     int numLegalMoves;
 }State;
 //all method calls occur after here
 #endif
```

Below this is the checkers.h file (it doesn't not include all other method calls beside PrintBoard()) and the checkers.c file (only includes the printBoard method and the Struct square call)

```
struct Square square[16][16];


void PrintBoard() {
int board[8][8];
int x,y;
char ch = 127;

for(y=0; y<8; y++)
{
   for(x=0; x<8; x++)
   {
       if(x%2 != y%2) {
           if(square[y][x].state) {
               if(square[y][x].col) 
               {
                  if(square[y][x].state == King) board[y][x] = 'B';
                  else board[y][x] = 'b';
               }
               else
               {
                  if(square[y][x].state == King) board[y][x] = 'A';
                  else board[y][x] = 'a';
               }
           } else board[y][x] = ' ';
       } else board[y][x] = ch;
       printf("%c",board[y][x]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}
}


 #ifndef CHECKERS_H
 #define CHECKERS_H

 #define Empty 0
 #define Piece 1
 #define King 2

 #define HUMAN 1
 #define COMPUTER 2

 struct Square {
         Widget widget;
         int val;
         int state;
         int col;
         int hilite;
 };

 void PrintBoard();
 #endif
```

I attempted to just call state->PrintBoard() but the program couldn't recognize the call. I also tried adding a Square struct to the State struct in the computer header file but that also created an error. I also created a new PrintBoard method in the computer.c file but it wouldn't know which color state was in each square.  Any help would be appreciated and I can post more code that I have if needed.

Comment: Why do you think PrintBoard is connected to state? Is this C or C++? I think you're confused. There's no such thing as classes or methods in C.

Comment: Our teacher gave us all the code to run this program except the actual search functions but asked us to print out the boards at each evaluation state using the PrintBoard() method from a different class. I was just having problems trying to figure out how to use that method for another class which needs access to the Square struct

Comment: A dirty way would be to define the PrintBoard() function outside any class and friend it in each class that you need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the way your code is currently written, `PrintBoard` is a stand-alone function as it should be in a C-program ... it's not a method of the `State` class like you would have with C++.  Therefore if you want to call `state->PrintBoard()`, you are going to have to make that function a method of the `State` class and use a C++ compiler to compiler your program... otherwise, if you want to keep it as a stand-alone function and use a C-compiler, you're going to have to add a `State*` argument to `PrintBoard`, and then call it like `PrintBoard(state)`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the method `PrintBoard()` inside the `State` struct and use C++ instead. Then you can call `state->PrintBoard()`.

```
 typedef struct{
   void PrintBoard() { // <---this is what you need to do
     ...
   }
   int player;
   char board[8][8];
   char movelist[48][12];  
   int numLegalMoves;
 }State;
```

If you don't want to do that, then call it like `PrintBoard(state)` and change the `PrintBoard` function.

And also, decide if you are doing Object-Oriented or not. You sound confused.

Comment: I didn't write any of this code. It was given to us by our teacher and we only needed to implement the actual search function. However, he wanted us to use his pre-written code and just modify it so you could print the board at each evaluation state to make sure that the heuristic function was correct.

Comment: Then just put that function in State class too. Also, what language are you using? C or C++?

Comment: We are using C for this program

Comment: Then why are you using Object-Oriented stuff? You cannot do `state->PrintBoard()` in C even if the `State` struct had a method called `PrintBoard()`.

Comment: That is what my teacher, when I asked him during his office hours, said I should be able to do with a few small tweaks to his code.

Comment: You cannot do `state->PrintBoard()` in C. Did he say you can do `state->PrintBoard()` with a few small tweaks? Or did he say you can print the board with a few small tweaks?

Comment: He actually said I could do state->PrintBoard() with a few small tweaks.

Comment: Nope... The only "small tweaks" possible would be to add a function ptr to you `State` class, but you'd still need to modify the arguments for `PrintBoard`to accept a pointer since C will not pass a hidden `this` pointer when you make the call.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm guessing our teacher forgot how he originally wrote this code since he hasn't taught it in a few years. Thank you all

Answer (score -2):

Most (if not all) game programmers use a one dimentional board. Also, for checkers you can omit half of the squares, since they are not used.

Comment: Yes, I know this is relevant but still not an answer...you should say this in a comment...